# How to automate a whole Python script to run via Airflow?

Tags: python, airflow

I have a Python script that points to an elasticsearch cluster, performs aggregations and computations on data, and then stores insights in a local PostgreSQL. The script can be run daily or weekly depending on the user preferences as follows:

```py
python script.py --approach daily 
python script.py --approach weekly
```

I want to automate this dataflow workflow process to be run every 10 minutes via Airflow.

My guess is to go for the bashoperator as to create a task `t1 = bashoperator` that executes the bash command `python script.py --approach daily` as a DAG1, and `t2 = bashoperator` that executes the bash command `python script.py --approach weekly`

The code didn't seem to give an appropriate result as the webUI of Airflow seems to schedule all jobs to scheduled.

Can anyone tell me what I have been doing wrong?

```
#imports 
    from airflow.models import DAG
    from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
    from  airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
    from  airflow.operators.email_operator import EmailOperator

    from datetime import datetime, timedelta

    seven_days_ago = datetime.combine(datetime.today() - timedelta(7),
                                        datetime.min.time())

    default_args = {
        
        'owner': 'me',
        'depends_on_past': False,
        'start_date': seven_days_ago,
        'email': ['me@gmail.com'],
        'email_on_failure': True,
        'email_on_retry': False
        'retries': 3,
        'max_tries' : 3 , 
        'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=10) 

        }

    etl_dag = DAG('tester',default_args=default_args,schedule_interval= '@once')

    #the bashoperator to execute the bash command as to automate the task execution every 5 min 
    weekly_task = BashOperator(
    task_id='testing',
    bash_command='python  my_script.py --approach weekly',
    dag=etl_dag)
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. You talk about executing script daily & weekly but you also talk about running it every 5/10 min. Can you please clarify what needs to be executed and when?

Comment: the goal is to automate the execution daily & weekly . I suggested 5 minutes just to see the logs and be sure that  it works properly rather than waiting a whole day to be triggered ...  but to clarify , what I want is the script to be automated daily and weekly . any ideas how ? thank you very much

Comment: NOTE : I can reformulate my question if you find it best to do so .

Comment: What did you try to achieve by setting datetime.combine in start_date?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your syntax, I'm going to assume you are running Airflow 1.10.14.

I think you are trying to accomplish the following:

- run my_script.py daily
- run my_script.py weekly

You will need to alter your script to do exactly one workflow cycle. This is because Airflow will be executing your script each schedule interval. If your script is ran and has an internal scheduling process (assuming that's what `--approach` determines), it will conflict with Airflow core purpose, which is to manage your workflows. Each time Airflow runs the script, it'll start another process that runs weekly (for `--approach weekly`) multiplying the workflows.

You want Airflow to schedule your workflow, not the script.

---

Two DAGs with separate schedule_interval will work here.

**daily_dag.py**

```py
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator

from datetime import datetime

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='daily_dag',
    start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1),
    schedule_interval='0 7 * * *'
)
with dag:
    run_script = BashOperator(
        task_id='run_script',
        bash_command='python my_script.py',
    )
```

This DAG will run the workflow every day at 7 UTC.

**weekly_run.py**

```py
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator

from datetime import datetime

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='weekly_dag',
    start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1),
    schedule_interval='0 7 * * Mon'
)
with dag:
    run_script = BashOperator(
        task_id='run_script',
        bash_command='python my_script.py',
    )
```

This DAG will run the workflow every Monday at 7 UTC.

Keeping them separate allows you to have a cleaner pipeline as well as clearer definition of what each pipeline does at their own frequencies.

I would also look into converting those BashOperator into [PythonOperators](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.14/howto/operator/python.html) to remove a layer of abstraction by executing the python code directly vs through a shell.

Comment: thanks for your help ! however , I still have all DAGRuns failed , I have a doubt it is because both daily_run.py and weekly_run.py use an elasticsearch query that performs aggregations starting from today's date date.now() and loop over backwards to 6 months before interval[date.now() - timedelta(months=6) , date.now() ] to return data insghts and store it in postgresql . So, my question , is it because of this , that all DAGRuns are failing  ?  NOTE : both daily_run.py and weekly_run.py are executed OK and returning outputs without errors when being ran ..

Answer (score 0):

You have several approaches here:

1. Write two DAGs. One for daily and one for weekly.
2. Write one DAG using the `DayOfWeekBranchOpeator` that will branch your workflow depending on the specific day. For example: On Monday it will perform `--approach weekly` and in all other days it will perform `--approach` daily.

If you are running **Airflow>= 2.1.0** (not yet released):

```
from airflow.operators.weekday import BranchDayOfWeekOperator
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator

with DAG(
    dag_id='tester',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval='@daily'
) as dag:

    branch_op = BranchDayOfWeekOperator(
        task_id="branch_task",
        follow_task_ids_if_true="weekly_task",
        follow_task_ids_if_false="daily_task",
        week_day="MONDAY", # Replace with the day you want to execute the approch weekly
        use_task_execution_day=False, # Set true if you want the day to be checked against execution_date
    )
    weekly_op = BashOperator(
        task_id='weekly_task',
        bash_command='python  my_script.py --approach weekly',
    )
    daily_op = BashOperator(
        task_id='daily_task',
        bash_command='python  my_script.py --approach daily',
    )

    branch_op >> [weekly_op, daily_op]
```

If you are running **Airflow< 2.1.0**:

Copy the [DayOfWeekBranchOpeator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/802159767baf1768d92c6047c2fdb2094ee7a2a8/airflow/operators/weekday.py#L27) code into your project, import it locally and use the same code as above.
The `DayOfWeekBranchOpeator` is new in Airflow 2.1 release.
Note that you might need to change a few imports in the operator depends which Airflow version you are running.

Comment: thanks for your help , but still facing the same problem  DAGRuns failed , I have a doubt it is because both daily_run.py and weekly_run.py use an elasticsearch query that performs aggregations starting from today's date date.now() and loop over backwards to 6 months before interval[date.now() - timedelta(months=6) , date.now() ] to return data insghts and store it in postgresql . So, my question , is it because of this , that all DAGRuns are failing ? NOTE : both daily_run.py and weekly_run.py run OK and return results . what did I do wrong ? thank you for your help !

Comment: It's impossible to assist like this. You need to post the actual traceback and the updated dag code. Also, what you describe is a different question - there is no postgres in the original question nor sending parameters from Airflow to your script